RSForm Modal form set value of dropdown on modal
I have an RSForm with a button to open a modal form using RSForm Plugin Modal.
I wish to set the value of a dropdown on the modal form using jQuery.
I do not know the id of the modal form that is created by the RSForm Plugin Modal, I think I need this to set the value of the DropDown
I have obtained the data from a field on my main form using jQuery.
$( "#BtnAddModel" ).on( "click", function() {
  
        var manufacturer = $("#ManufacturerDropDown").val();

} );

I would like to pre-select a dropdown called "ManufacturerDropDown" in a form on the modal.
